# Return list of active bits

Tags: python, bit

How I can get a list of all active bits (active bit when equal to 1)?

Example: number `220` in decimal is `11011100` in binary so it should return `['2', '3', '4', '6', '7']` because bits 0, 1 and 5 are off .

Comment: Which bit of this are you stuck on? Converting `220` to a binary string? Finding the "active" bits? Why is the output a list of strings?! Where is your code so far, and what exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: I know how to convert dec to bin , what I want to do is to return a list with bit position of active bit (bits equal to 1)

Comment: how are 0,1 and 5 off in your example?

Comment: @user2776193 so, again, what exactly is wrong with your code? Do you know how to iterate over a string? How to test whether one character equals another? How to get the indices? **This isn't a code-writing service.**

Comment: @PadraicCunningham The MSB is usually on the right side. The first bit is referred to as the 0th bit by the OP, so `11011100` has 0 1 and 5 on 0 (off) and 2 3 4 6 and 7 on 1 (on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative dirty one liner (no strings attached):

```
input_number = 220

print [i for i in xrange(input_number.bit_length()) if ((1 << i) & input_number)]
```

Comment: thanks, work like a charm

Answer (score 2):

`[2:]` removes binary prefix, `[::-1]` reverses the result

```
In [5]: [x for x, y in enumerate(bin(220)[2:][::-1]) if y != '0']
Out[5]: [2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
```

Alternatively you can use `[-1:1:-1]` as @jonrsharpe suggested:

```
In [6]: [x for x, y in enumerate(bin(220)[-1:1:-1]) if y != '0']
Out[6]: [2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Much neater to use `[-1:1:-1]` and `if int(y)`

Comment: Or you can use `'{:b}'.format(220)[::-1]`

Comment: or just simply and probably faster  `[i for i,j in enumerate(s[::-1]) if j =="1"]`

Comment: I removed `int` conversion, because direct comprehension is twice faster.

Answer (score 1):

A dirty one-liner:

```
print [i for (i,b) in (enumerate(reversed("{0:b}".format(220)))) if int(b)]
# [2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
```

Comment: This is very inefficient.

Comment: Yes (if that's what you're interested in)

Answer (score 1):

a little different implementation using [itertools.compress()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress)

```
x=list(map(int,bin(220)[2:]))
print list(compress(range(len(x)-1,-1,-1), x))
#output [7, 6, 4, 3, 2]
```